# Moving files that meet extension and size criteria to a different folder via terminal

Tags: command-line, mv

Due to a series of unfortunate incidents, I lost all my data during a botched system update (noob here). I managed to use photorec to recover files to a specific folder "temp" on my desktop. I want to recover all my baby pics, so most likely JPEG that are more than 1MB in size. Since the number of files in the "temp" folder are in the thousands and have files of extension "txt", "png", "jpg", and others, my computer freezes if I try to use the GUI to find and move files.

Is there a way for me to move all JPGs that are more than 1MB in size to a different folder "temp2" via terminal? Current OS is a fresh, minimal installation of 18.04.

Comment: [This `find` command](https://askubuntu.com/a/509202/158442) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/962872/158442) can be combined and adapted to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot muru! I did search but missed the earlier question you identified. I'm taking baby steps in Linux, so pardon any faux pas.